# Search for string in multiple files go to next file after 1st occurrence in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 10k of html files and about 3k of them include youtube video embed code, so i search for the string to get list of those files like this:

```
$LocalListOfYTPosts = Get-ChildItem "$outputfolder*.html" -recurse |
     Select-String -pattern "https://www.youtube.com/embed" | 
     group path | 
     select name -ExpandProperty Name
```

Youtube embed code is included only once per file, so i thought that i could speed things up if search will go to next file after 1st occurrence of the string (I'm not sure if that's actually correct)

Is there a way to tell to powershell to go to next file if the string has been found in in the current one?

Comment: Try the `-List` option on `Select-String`: Returns only the first match in each input file. By default, Select-String returns a MatchInfo object for each match it finds.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit, time from 39 seconds dropped to 35 so not a big difference, but every little helps :)

Comment: You could try parallelizing the processing of the files using workflows but as this is mostly IO bound, it might make matters worse. There's nothing lost in trying though. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19727899/52598) SO question that can be used as a template.

Answer (score 1):

(Comment -> Answer)

Try the `-List` option on [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

> Returns only the first match in each input file. By default, Select-String returns a MatchInfo object for each match it finds.