# Limit number of Start-Process running in powershell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, powershell-2.0, start-job, start-process

I have tried to limit the number of `Start-Process` running from a Powershell, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried to follow this process: https://exchange12rocks.org/2015/05/24/how-to-limit-a-number-of-powershell-jobs-running-simultaneously/ and [Run N parallel jobs in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781666/run-n-parallel-jobs-in-powershell/8782031#8782031)

But these are for Jobs not Processes, and I would like to remove the `-Wait` from the `Start-Process`

My concern with the script is that if there are 1000 audio files in the folder, then FFMpeg would crash the system.

---

```
# get the folder for conversion
function mbAudioConvert {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    $fileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $fileBrowser.SelectedPath = "B:\"
    $fileBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
    $fileBrowser.Description = "Select the folder with the audio which you wish to convert to Avid DNxHD 120 25P 48kHz"

    $mbLoop     = $true
    $mbCount    = 0001
    $mbMaxJob   = 4

    while( $mbLoop ) {
        if( $fileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq "OK" ) {
            $mbLoop     = $false


            $mbImage    = ( Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\lib\AudioOnly.jpg" )
            $mbff32     = ( Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\lib\ffmpeg32.exe" )
            $mbff64     = ( Get-Item -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\lib\ffmpeg64.exe" )

            $mbFolder   = $fileBrowser.SelectedPath
            $mbItemInc  = ( ls $mbFolder\* -Include *.mp3, *.MP3, *.wav*, *.WAV*, *.ogg, *.OGG, *.wma, *.WMA, *.flac, *.FLAC, *.m4a, *.M4a )
            $mbProgress = ( Get-ChildItem -Path $mbItemInc )

            $mbHasRaw   = ( $mbFolder + "\RAW" )

            if( !( Test-Path -Path $mbHasRaw ) ) {
                # force create a RAW folder if it does not exist
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$mbHasRaw"
            }


            foreach( $mbItem in $mbItemInc ) {

                $mbCheck    = $false

                # output the progress
                # Suggestion: You might want to consider updating this after starting the job and do the final update after running ex. Get-Job | Wait-Job to make the progress-bar stay until all processes are finished
                #Write-Progress -Activity "Counting files for conversion" -status "Currently processing: $mbCount" -percentComplete ($mbCount / $mbItemInc.count*100)

                # limit the run number
                while ($mbCheck -eq $false) {

                    if( (Get-Job -State 'Running').count -lt $mbMaxJob) {

                        $mbScriptBlock = {
                            $mbItemName = $using:mbItem.BaseName

                            $mbNewItem  = ( $using:mbFolder + "\RAW\" + $mbItemName + ".mov" )
                            $mbArgs     = " -loop 1 -i $using:mbImage -i $using:mbItem -shortest -c:v dnxhd -b:v 120M -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48k -af loudnorm=I=-12 $mbNewItem"

                            Start-Process -FilePath $using:mbff32 -ArgumentList $mbArgs -NoNewWindow -Wait
                        }

                        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $mbScriptBlock

                        #The job-thread doesn't know about $mbCount, better to increment it after starting the job
                        $mbCount++
                        $mbCheck  = $true          
                    }

                }
            }

        } else {

            $mbResponse = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You have exited out of the automation process!", "User has cancelled")
            if( $mbResponse -eq "OK" ) {
                return
            }
        }
    }

    $fileBrowser.SelectedPath
    $fileBrowser.Dispose()
}

# call to function
mbAudioConvert
```

Comment: You need `-Wait` to know when the process end so you can count concurrent processes. The alternative is a `Get-Process`-loop. Why not use jobs as you describe with `Star-Process -Wait` in the job scriptblock?

Comment: @FrodeF. I haven't really been able to figure it out. Every time I try to run it through a job it doesn't do the video conversion from the Start-Process within the scriptblock

Comment: Update the question with the code, error and expected behavior from that attempt so we can help you troubleshoot. We're here to help you fix your own code, not write it for you.

Comment: @FrodeF. I have added the script section I was trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You edit `$mbCheck`, but the while loop is testing `$Check` which means the while-loop will never execute as `$Check -eq $false` is `$false` when `$Check` is not defined
2. Variables created outside the job script-block needs to be passed as an argument or you need to use the `using:` variable-scope to pass them in (PowerShell 3.0 or later). Added it to `$mbItem`, `$mbff32`, `$mbImage` and `$mbFolder` in the example which were not defined.
3. `$mbMaxJob` is not defined. The get running jobs-check will never be true and no processes will start
4. `$mbCount` not defined. Progress bar won't work
5. `echo "$mbCount. $mbNewItem"` won't return anything unless you use `Receive-Job` at some point to get the output from a job

Try:

```
#DemoValues
$mbItemInc = 1..10 | % { New-Item -ItemType File -Name "File$_.txt" }
$mbff32 = "something32"
$mbFolder = "c:\FooFolder"
$mbImage = "BarImage"
$mbMaxJob = 2
$mbCount = 0

foreach( $mbItem in $mbItemInc ) {

    $mbCheck    = $false

    # output the progress
    # Suggestion: You might want to consider updating this after starting the job and do the final update after running ex. Get-Job | Wait-Job to make the progress-bar stay until all processes are finished
    Write-Progress -Activity "Counting files for conversion" -status "Currently processing: $mbCount" -percentComplete ($mbCount / $mbItemInc.count*100)

    # limit the run number
    while ($mbCheck -eq $false) {

        if ((Get-Job -State 'Running').count -lt $mbMaxJob) {

            $mbScriptBlock = {

                 Param($mbItem, $mbFolder, $mbImage, $mbff32)
                #Filename without extension is already available in a FileInfo-object using the BaseName-property
                $mbItemName = $mbItem.BaseName

                $mbNewItem  = ( $mbFolder + "\RAW\" + $mbItemName + ".mov" )
                $mbArgs     = "-loop 1 -i $mbImage -i $mbItem -shortest -c:v dnxhd -b:v 120M -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48k -af loudnorm=I=-12 $mbNewItem"

                Start-Process -FilePath $mbff32 -ArgumentList $mbArgs -NoNewWindow -Wait
            }

            Start-Job -ScriptBlock $mbScriptBlock -ArgumentList $mbItem, $mbFolder, $mbImage, $mbff32

            #The job-thread doesn't know about $mbCount, better to increment it after starting the job
            $mbCount++
            $mbCheck  = $true          
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to have your part in there. Still doesn't run but maybe the full code can help?

Comment: Where's your `$mbMaxJob` defined?

Comment: Sorry, error in the copy paste. It is at the top under `$mbCount`

Comment: Which PSVersion are you running? I mentioned `$using:` is a 3.0+ feature, but your question is tagged with 2.0.  Also. Try adding some comments like `"before while-loop $mbItem"`, `"starting job $mbItem"` in your script so you can pinpoint where it stops. Does the Progress-bar move or is it stuck on the first status?

Comment: When I use your script in PS3+ it works. If I port it to PS2 and use the original code to get the file base name, or the Start-Process call to the mbff32 nothing happens.

Comment: As mentioned, `$using:` won't work with PS2.0. I've updated the answer to make it support 2.0. Still, you should update Powershell as it brings many benefits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166209/discussion-between-ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv-and-frode-f).

Answer (score 0):

I propose you my solution :

```
cls

$FormatNameJob="FFMPEG"
$maxConcurrentJobs = 100
$DirWithFile="C:\temp"
$DestFolder="C:\temp2"
$TraitmentDir="C:\temp\traitment"
$PathFFMpeg="C:\Temp\ffmpeg\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$HistoFolder="C:\temp\histo"

#create dir if dont exists
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $TraitmentDir -Force | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestFolder -Force | Out-Null
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $HistoFolder -Force | Out-Null


while ($true)
{
    "Loop File"

    $ListeFile=Get-ChildItem $DirWithFile -file -Filter "*.avi"

    if ($ListeFile.count -eq 0 )
    {
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
       continue 
    }

    #loop file to trait
    $ListeFile | %{

        while ((get-job -State Running | where Name -eq $FormatNameJob ).Count -ge $maxConcurrentJobs)
        {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            get-job -State Completed | where Name -eq $FormatNameJob | Remove-Job
        }

        "traitment file : {0}" -f $_.Name

        #build newname and move item into traitment dir
        $NewfileName="{0:yyyyMMddHHmmssfffff}_{1}" -f (get-date), $_.Name
        $ItemTraitment=[io.path]::Combine($TraitmentDir, $NewfileName)
        $mbNewItem  ="{0}.mov" -f [io.path]::Combine($DestFolder, $_.BaseName)
        Move-item $_.FullName -Destination $ItemTraitment

        #build arguments and command
        $mbArgs     = " -loop 1 -i $ItemTraitment -shortest -c:v dnxhd -b:v 120M -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 25 -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 48k -af loudnorm=I=-12 $mbNewItem"

        $ScriptBlock=[scriptblock]::Create("Start-Process $PathFFMpeg -ArgumentList $mbArgs -Wait")

        #add job
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Name $FormatNameJob
    }

}
```